# XLRD: Successfully extracted 2 lists out of 2 sheets, but list comparison won't work

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

Ok so I have two xlsx sheets, both sheets have in their second column, at index 1, a list of sim card numbers. I have successfully printed the contents of both columns into my powershell terminal as 2 lists, and the quantity of elements in those lists, after extracting that data using xlrd.

The first sheet (theirSheet) has 454 entries, the second (ourSheet) has 361. I need to find the 93 that don't exist in the second sheet and put them into (unpaidSims). I could do this manually of course, but I would like to automate this task for the future when I inevitably need to do it again so I am trying to write this python script.

Considering python agrees that I have a list of 454 entries, and a list of 361 entries, I thought I just need to figure out a list comparison and I researched that on Stack Overflow, and tried 3 times with 3 different solutions, but each time, when I use that script to produce the third list (unpaidSims), it says 454...meaning it hasn't removed the entries that are duplicated in the smaller list. Please advise.

```
from os.path import join, dirname, abspath
import xlrd

theirBookFileName = join(dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__))), 'pycel', 'theirBook.xlsx')

ourBookFileName = join(dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__))), 'pycel', 'ourBook.xlsx')

theirBook = xlrd.open_workbook(theirBookFileName)

ourBook = xlrd.open_workbook(ourBookFileName)

theirSheet = theirBook.sheet_by_index(0)

ourSheet = ourBook.sheet_by_index(0)

theirSimColumn = theirSheet.col(1)

ourSimColumn = ourSheet.col(1)

numColsTheirSheet = theirSheet.ncols

numRowsTheirSheet = theirSheet.nrows

numColsOurSheet = ourSheet.ncols

numRowsOurSheet = ourSheet.nrows

# First Attempt at the comparison, but fails and returns 454 entries from the bigger list
unpaidSims = [d for d in theirSimColumn if d not in ourSimColumn]
print unpaidSims
lengthOfUnpaidSims = len(unpaidSims)
print lengthOfUnpaidSims
print "\nWe are expecting 93 entries in this new list"

# Second Attempt at the comparison, but fails and returns 454 entries from the bigger list
s = set(ourSimColumn)
unpaidSims = [x for x in theirSimColumn if x not in s]
print unpaidSims
lengthOfUnpaidSims = len(unpaidSims)
print lengthOfUnpaidSims

# Third Attempt at the comparison, but fails and returns 454 entries from the bigger list
unpaidSims = tuple(set(theirSimColumn) - set(ourSimColumn))
print unpaidSims
lengthOfUnpaidSims = len(unpaidSims)
print lengthOfUnpaidSims
```

Comment: Are you sure that all the entries in the smaller list are also in the larger list?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [xlrd Documentation](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.sheet.Sheet.col), the `col` method returns "a sequence of the `Cell` objects in the given column".

It doesn't mention anything about comparison of `Cell` objects. Digging into [the source](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/blob/master/xlrd/sheet.py#L2224), it appears that they didn't code any comparison methods into the class. As such, the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__) states that the objects will be compared by "object identity". In other words, the comparison will be `False` unless they are the *exact same instance of the `Cell` class*, even if the values they contain are identical.

You need to compare the `value`s of the `Cell`s instead. For example:

```
unpaidSims = set(sim.value for sim in theirSimColumn) - set(sim.value for sim in ourSimColumn)
```